# Symfony fatal error

Tags: symfony

Symfony runs correctly but I get this error after I open in browser All my controller is empty Response

```
FatalThrowableError

Type error: Return value of Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader() must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Annotations\void, none returned
```

Here is my config file, I use multiple database

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: admin
        connections:
            admin:
                driver: pdo_mysql
                host: '%database_host%'
                port: '%database_port%'
                dbname: '%database_name%'
                user: '%database_user%'
                password: '%database_password%'
                charset: UTF8
            public_branch:
                driver: pdo_mysql
                host: '%database_host1%'
                port: '%database_port1%'
                dbname: '%database_name1%'
                user: '%database_user1%'
                password: '%database_password1%'
                charset: UTF8

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        default_entity_manager: admin
        entity_managers:
            admin:
                connection: admin
                auto_mapping: true
            public_branch:
                connection: public_branch
                mappings:
                    AdminBundle: ~
                    PublicBranchBundle: ~
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved this problem by updating my php from **7.0** to **7.1** ,  using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.1-curl php7.1-xml php7.1-zip php7.1-gd php7.1-mysql php7.1-mbstring php7.1
```

Comment: Does not work for me with PHP 7.1.6-1~ubuntu16.10.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Jun  9 2017 08:27:12) ( NTS ) and PHP 7.1.7-1+ubuntu16.10.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Jul  7 2017 09:42:38) ( NTS ) - fresh installation created using symfony installer

Comment: Is it your defualt php version? What did you get with php -v ?

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately not every prod server can be upgraded that simply.

Recent Doctrine updates require PHP **7.1.**.

You can downgrade ORM to **2.5** and necessarily Annotations to **1.4**:

```
    "doctrine/orm": "2.5.6",
    "doctrine/annotations": "1.4.*",
    "doctrine/dbal": "2.5.4",
```

This way you can still use PHP **7.0**.

Comment: I guess you had something like "dev-master" or "2.*" in your composer (you didn't post it).
Be sure to you fixed versions to prevent this kind of stuff. :)

Comment: no all are stable version the composer file is created with symfony installer

Comment: For sure. But did you set php version fixes to 7.0 and not 7.*?

Answer (score 10):

What the problem fixed for me was, *after* upgrading to **PHP 7.1**, also enable PHP 7.1 for **apache2** by

```
$ sudo a2enmod php7.1
```

I also had to disable PHP 7.0 for some reason:

```
$ sudo a2dismod php7.0
```

Comment: I had the same error, thanks to note of disable older version! Great!

Answer (score 1):

If some still facing same problem either move to php 7.1 or simply do

```
composer update
```

it will automatically downgrade doctrine/annotations from 1.5 to 1.4 which work with php < 7.1