# Doctrine annotation not working on PHP 7.0

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations

I'm stuck with a problem which looks quite small but I can't manage to solve it. 
It's probably very silly, but I cannot find any solution.

I'm developing a Symfony 3 application with PHP 7.1 on my PC. Everything is working well. I tried to upload it on my host server which is using PHP 7.0.

When I start the website, I get this error message :

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Return value of Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader() must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Annotations\void, none returned in /home/clients/fb3f5a508aeeb6d39e6d7e1e47bda9ac/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationRegistry.php:117 Stack trace: #0 /home/clients/fb3f5a508aeeb6d39e6d7e1e47bda9ac/app/autoload.php(9): Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(Array) #1 /home/clients/fb3f5a508aeeb6d39e6d7e1e47bda9ac/web/app.php(6): require('/home/clients/f...') #2 {main} thrown in /home/clients/fb3f5a508aeeb6d39e6d7e1e47bda9ac/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationRegistry.php on line 117

I found those to links which seem to be very helpful:
 - [Symfony fatal error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45279214/symfony-fatal-error)
 - http://www.doctrine-project.org/2017/07/25/php-7.1-requirement-and-composer.html

But, I couldn't solve the issue. I cannot find which version I need to be compatible with PHP 7.0...

In my composer json config file, I have:

```
"platform": {
    "php": "7.0"
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
    "misd/phone-number-bundle": "^1.2",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3.10",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.3.*",
    "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0"
},
```

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Try deleting your `vendor` directory and re-running composer install. I had similar issues before and that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! :-) I downloaded the version 1.2.7 of annotations from the website of Doctrine and it worked. http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/annotations.html

The weird thing is that on their website, they say that the last version is 1.2.7 but I could download the version 1.4.0 with Composer...

Answer (score 5):

Your `platform` setting is ignored as you did not wrap it inside the `config` node. The following config would be working:

```
{
    "config": {
        "platform": {
            "php": "7.0"
        },
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
        "misd/phone-number-bundle": "^1.2",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3.10",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.3.*",
        "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it, but it still doesn't update or downgrade anything. :-/

Comment: Can you show the full output that you got with this `composer.json` file when running `composer update -vvv`?

Answer (score 4):

If you use platform as "php": "7.0" then you will try by this

```
  "require": {
        "php" : ">=7.0.21",
        "symfony/symfony" : "3.3.4",
        "doctrine/orm" : "2.5.10",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle" : "1.6.8",
        "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle" : "1.3.0",
        ...
```

If you strictly define version for all it will easy to find version specific bug.

this is working good for me.

Comment: Thanks! I tried, but I got these errors when updating with Composer:
Problem 1
    - The requested package doctrine/orm (locked at v2.5.6, required as 2.5.10) is satisfiable by doctrine/orm[v2.5.6] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

Comment: Problem 2
    - The requested package doctrine/doctrine-bundle (locked at 1.6.7, required as 1.6.8) is satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-bundle[1.6.7] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

Comment: Problem 3
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony 3.3.4 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.3.4].
    - Conclusion: don't install twig/twig v2.4.3
    - Conclusion: don't install twig/twig v2.4.2
    - Conclusion: don't install twig/twig v2.4.1
    - Conclusion: don't install twig/twig v2.4.0
... See next comment...

Comment: - Conclusion: don't install twig/twig v1.34.4
    - Conclusion: don't install twig/twig v1.34.3
    - Conclusion: don't install twig/twig v1.34.2
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.34.0, v1.33.2].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.34.0, v1.33.2].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.34.0, v1.33.2].
    - symfony/symfony v3.3.4 requires twig/twig ~1.34|~2.4 -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v1.34.0, v1.34.1, v1.34.2, v1.34.3, v1.34.4, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3].
...See next comment...

Comment: - Conclusion: don't install twig/twig v1.34.1
    - Installation request for twig/twig (locked at v1.33.2, required as ^1.0||^2.0) -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v1.33.2].

Comment: Glad to help you @Rafaël Moser

Answer (score 3):

The right way is to check which php you have:

```
php --version
```

then tell that composer to automatically blacklist not matching versions

```
composer config platform.php 7.0.17
```

then see if composer can downgrade that package (and only that package, we don't want unrelated updates; dry-run = only see, don't do)

```
composer update doctrine/common --with-dependencies --dry-run
```

and in my case composer told me that we also need to downgrade another package, so i finally did

```
composer update doctrine/common symfony/dom-crawler --with-dependencies
```

which worked out.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem was solved when I ran:

`composer update --with-dependencies`

This pulled in the missing `doctrine/annotations` dependency that was missed when I ran just `composer update`

`...
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing doctrine/annotations (1.7.x-dev 232c5da): Cloning 232c5da390 from cache
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
...`